# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Tags: python, string, dataframe, csv, floating-point

My code-

```
out = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    name = " ".join(row[0:4])

    entities = []
    i = 0
    for n in row.index[0:4]:
        entities.append([i, i + len(row[n]), n])
        i += len(row[n])+1
    out.append([name, {"entities": entities}])
```

My Dataframe-

```
             house                  road                        sub_area
0         726/30/3                 road 10                         abcd   
1              977                 road 16                         efgh
```

I am getting the error

```
line 12, in <module>
    name = " ".join(row[0:4])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without having knowing what `df` is, we can only guess. But usually the problem is that one is trying to `str.join` something else than strings. So try this instead:

```
name = " ".join(map(str, row[0:4]))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my dataframe

Comment: @bellatrix You get that error at the same line as before?

Comment: line 17, in <module>
    entities.append([i, i + len(row[n]), n])
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: @bellatrix Then `row[n]` is a float, which does not have a length. Maybe you want to convert the float to a string first?